# Flashback occurs when running the selenium library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a novice computer student from China. Recently, when I was learning the selenium library in Python, I followed the following code, but a flashback occurred.

```
from selenium import webdriver

# 创建Chrome浏览器对象
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
# 加载指定的页面
browser.get('https://www.baidu.com/')
```

The latest version of the Chrome browser I use, the kernel is 111.0.5563.147, and I also downloaded the 111.0.5563.64 driver from the Chrome driver website, which is also recommended by Google, and then I put it in the directory where I installed Python , the code is shown in the figure below, but I found that it crashed, does anyone know why?

I have tried changing the driver but it doesn't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Wu5.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Heyaa, Drivers issue is one the common issue, you can use this method to automatically download drivers, your code still works even if chrome version changed the drivers will also get updated

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

import chromedriver_autoinstaller
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

# 创建Chrome浏览器对象
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
# 加载指定的页面
browser.get('https://www.baidu.com/')
time.sleep(10)
```

**Alternate Method:**

```py
from selenium import webdriver

import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

# 创建Chrome浏览器对象
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
# 加载指定的页面
browser.get('https://www.baidu.com/')
```

now just run the program as you normally would.
don't forget to install the package,

```
pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller
```

Comment: Ok, I've done what you said, it's a good Python library, but it still doesn't solve my problem, because my Chrome driver is currently up to date, but this method solves what I may encounter in the future to the question, thank you.

Comment: @xixibox can you please share the screenshot, i may have misinterpreted your question. you can also share gifs too.

Comment: Ok, I inserted the image, sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow and just found a place to insert an image.

Comment: @xixibox ohhhh it's not an issue, it's just that program got finished that's why it closed the browser in the end. use time.sleep() or deattach functionality. check the updated code.

Comment: @xixibox i have updated the answer, check again if it works mark the question as answered